# Changing actionBar dropdown background color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

[image]

How do i change the color of the background where it says "add contact" and "about". Now its kind of grayish, but i want it to be white! This is a actionBar with dropdown, not a spinner. And im not using that actionbarsherlock thing.

Comment: which theme are you using for your application?

Answer (score 7):

For example, in you exisiting parent `Style` definition, add just the `android:popupMenuStyle` attribute as shown below:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    .......
    .......
</style>
```

And override the `android:popupMenuStyle` attribute by defining your style:

```
<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>
```

The `@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example` is this:

[image]

You can either choose to use an image similar to the one above, or use an `Color` resource.

And this is for the default *ActionBar*. Not the `ActionBarSherlock`. ;-)

`ActionBar` styles can be easily created using this cool website: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/. I usually experiment a little here before deciding on the style. Plus, it lets you download the styles and all necessary resources. Just plug them in your app and you are good to go. :-)

**UPDATED:** I think I caused some confusion which has resulted in the loss of the shadow on your app's drop-down. You may have replaced all the `<items>` in your `Style` that I listed in the original suggestion. The edit should fix that.

**UPDATE 2:**

Use these image resources instead of the `@android:color/white` value you are currently using. These are in the order of XHDPI, HDPI and MDPI. Save them and use them in the Style definition.

[image]    [image]    [image]

Comment: popupBackground worked, but now i miss shadows on the box. Is there a way to code it easier, instead of adding all those other lines

Comment: @Codebox: Sorry for the delay. I think it's my fault for the confusion. You do not need to add the rest of the lines. Just the edit in a couple of minutes. Sorry. :-(

Comment: I only added those lines that you have right now, but the shadow still got removed. And im using @android:color/white for android:popupBackground

Comment: @Codebox: Aah. That is because the `@android:color/white` does not have a shadow. If you notice the attached image, it has a shadow of it's own. Let me create a quick set of images that you can use instead of the `@android:color/white` attribute. That will get your shadows back. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get styles from [ActionBarStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) service. It has preview and makes all necessary drawable, xml and styles. 
There you can easily find and change required color and then find it in sources (in your case it is android:popupBackground).

Answer (score 0):

You can simple override itemBackground item in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
</style>
```