# How to change drop down menu background color for AppCompat theme?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-styles

I try to change drop-down menu background, but can't find right decision. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqO4j.png

That is ../values-v21/styles.xml I used

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Explain, please, how I can change background color there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15427218

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar in your layout?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, I'm using a standard toolbar.

Comment: @Sree thank you, but It's not working. I think it's because I'm using AppCompat instead of ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Toolbar you can use something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_main"
    app:popupTheme="@style/popupTheme"
    ...../>
```

where popupTheme is:

```
<style name="popupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/myPopupBackgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. I think it's a little cleaner to use `app:popupTheme="?attr/actionBarPopupTheme"` and specify the theme in the top level style, so the styling is picked up directly from the theme and no manual changes will be needed if you for instance changed to a different component for the action bar or are using different action bar implementations in different parts of the app.